# Assign multiple webcams to fixed /dev/video* at boot

Tags: boot, video, webcam

I'm currently working on a project that requires taking pictures with 3 USB webcams but whenever I boot the raspberry, it assigns randomly a /dev/video "address" to each one of them. I'm not using  the camera module for the raspberry so they usually get the /dev/video0, /dev/video2 and /dev/video4. I've read that for USB devices you have to modify the rules of the raspberry but I don't know how to do it with webcams.

Comment: The "rules" referred to are for `udev`; more specifically you want to add a `SYMLINK` based on the camera's USB ID or some other unique characteristic.  This is a bit technical but there are lots of examples if you search around.